# android my code show Array index out of bound error

Tags: android

this is my code is run perfectly if directry contain any image but if directory contain no image (0)  code will blast and show  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException    error what do ido?   how do i load blank or null gridview???
 this is image of my display http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2zyda9f&s=5  when i click photos(3) is workfine when i click hello(0) code will blast  show on log eror message 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
    GridView gridView;
  TextView textView;
File currentParent;
File[] currentFiles;
String[] currentFilePath;
boolean CheckArr[]; 
File root1;
LinearLayout ll;
String filePath;
String PhotosFolder = "Photos Folders";

SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;

List<ImageData> imList;

 Button del;
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

del = (Button) findViewById(R.id.canceles);
del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        for(int i=0;i<CheckArr.length;i++)
        {
            if(CheckArr[i] == true)
            {

                    File file = new 
  File(imList.get(i).getImgPath());
                    file.delete();
            }
        }


        inflateListView(currentFiles);
    }
 });


 ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout1);
 viewLoad = LayoutInflater.from(FileGridActivity.this).inflate(
        R.layout.main, null);
 AddPictures = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_privacy_contact);

  Addfolder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Addfolder);

 textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_name);
 File photos = new File(getFilesDir(), "Photos");
 photos.mkdirs();

 root1 = new File("/data/data/com.myexample/files/");

 currentParent = root1;
 currentFiles = root1.listFiles();


 currentFilePath = new String[currentFiles.length];
 int count = 0;

 for (File f : currentFiles) {
    currentFilePath[count] = f.getAbsolutePath();
    count++;

 }

 gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
 gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

        if (currentFiles[position].isDirectory() ) {


            root = new File("/data/data/com.myexample/files/"+ 
         FileName(currentFilePath[position]) + "/");

            currentFiles = root.listFiles();
            inflateListView(currentFiles);
        } else if (currentFiles[position].isFile()) {
            openFile(currentFiles[position]);

            // gridposition = currentFiles[(int) id]);

        }           }
   });


          private void inflateListView(File[] files) {

 imList = new ArrayList<ImageData>();
 ImageData imObj;

 List<Map<String, Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

 boolean check;

 for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    Map<String, Object> listItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();





    if (files[i].isDirectory()) {





        listItem.put("icon", R.drawable.folder);
        listItem.put("fileName",files[i].getName() + "(" + 
    files[i].list().length + ")");

        listItems.add(listItem);

        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, 
   R.layout.line,new String[] { "icon", "fileName" }, new int[] { 
       R.id.icon,R.id.file_name });
    //  gridView.invalidateViews();
        gridView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    //  simpleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        check = false;
    } 
    else 
    {   
        check = true;
        imObj = new ImageData();




        listItem.put("icon", files[i]);

        listItems.add(listItem);

        imObj.setImgPath(files[i].toString());

        imList.add(imObj);

        }


    if(check == true)
    {
        imageAdapter = new          


      ImagesAdapter(getApplicationContext(),FileGridActivity.this,0,imList);      
        gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}



  }

  public class ImagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageData> {

 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 List<ImageData> listItems;

 public ImagesAdapter(Context context,Activity activity, int 
   textViewResourceId, List<ImageData> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.listItems = items;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        CheckArr = new boolean[items.size()];

        for(int z = 0; z<CheckArr.length;z++)
            CheckArr[z] = false;
 }

 public class ViewHolder{

       public CheckBox checkbox;
       public ImageView imageview;

 }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

            vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);


            ImageData o = listItems.get(position);

            if(o != null){
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.imageview = (ImageView) 
  vi.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) 
vi.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);

                File f = new 
  File(listItems.get(position).getImgPath());
                holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(f));

                holder.checkbox.setId(position);
                holder.imageview.setId(position);

                holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
    OnCheckedChangeListener() {                 
                    public void 
   onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated 
 method stub
                        Log.e("id",arg0.getId()+" 
  ");
                        Log.e("bool",arg1+ " ");

                        CheckArr[arg0.getId()] = 
    arg1;

                    }
                });

            }

        return vi;

    }
```

Comment: plz also add log with question if app is crashing.

Comment: wow..Just indent your code. Always make sure that you use Ctrl+shift+F for indenting in eclipse.

Comment: ok im sorry jus tell me what do i do? why my code is crash if directory contain (0) element??

Comment: @hayyaanam: hi Hayya, i which line u are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in current code?

Comment: in this line

    if (currentFiles[position].isDirectory() ) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding ,you are trying to access a index that does not exist.

It's simple

Just check

in case of arraylist

```
yourarray.size();
```

or 
in case of array

```
yourarray.length;
```

if this returns a value more than 0 then execute :

```
photos(3); //whatever code you are using to retrieve data from the array
```

Something like this :

```
if(yourArray.getCount()>0){

//fetch the required data

}
else{

Log.v("TAG ","No data");

}
```